# Deadlock issue after upgrade IBM Datastage and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, deadlock, datastage

I just upgraded Datastage from 6.x to 11.x and SQL Server 2008 to 2016.
I don't understand why after upgrading, deadlocks often occur. The upgrade method that I use only moves jobs on Datastage and move databases on SQL Server.

SSMS deadlock report
[image]

Based on this article: [link](https://docs-ugi.mybluemix.net/docs/content/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.trouble.ref.doc/topics/teraconnector03.html)

Does that apply to SQL Server too? Is there anything I should pay attention to from this new environment?

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting deadlocks for "Server" jobs or "Parallel" jobs?

In 11.7, the default apt configuration file (/opt/IBM/InformationServer/Server/Configurations/default.apt) is a 2-node configuration file.  That means parallel jobs running parallel stages (such as the ODBC Connector stage that could be used to connect to an SQL Server database) runs 2 copies in parallel, each processing part of the data.   If the job is only doing inserts, it should not deadlock table, but if job is doing parallel upserts (inserts and updates at same time, from 2 different database connections), then a deadlock could occur If you are using default partition method rather than use hash partition on key records to ensure all records with same key are handled by the same database connection.

In DataStage version 6 (over 10 years old), I am not sure job stages had option to run in parallel.

In any case, for your current job that is deadlocking, you can either backup then update default.apt to be a one-node config file (so all jobs would then run on one node which would avoid a job deadlock with self, but would also require more time for job to complete), or a better option would be to make copy of default.apt, one-node.apt, edit it to one node config file, then add to job the environment variable APT_CONFIG_FILE and set it to absolute path to the one node config file, so job will run on one node.  If it no longer hangs then that is indication that job was deadlocking itself and to run on 2-nodes or more you should examine partition method used for records going to database stage.

If the failing job is a Server job, using one of the old server plug-in stages on Server canvas, then I would not expect database to deadlock, unless it is run at same time as another job updating the same database table.

Comment: hi brian,
thank you for your answer..
to be honest i am a new on datastage, i will try your suggestion to reconfigure apt confog file.